# Powershell script to find file age on multiple shares

Tags: arrays, powershell

I'm working on a powershell script to read file attributes filtered by  CreationTime on multiple shares. The scripts works, sporadically. It works great when I use a single path but I get mixed results when I add the folders paths to an array. The most disturbing result is when it successfully find and reads all path and then includes everything under c:windows\system32. Same anomaly when shares are empty.

So what I want to accomplish is:

1. Read list of Shares
2. Read each share content filtered by 'CreationTime' and 'Archive' attributes.
3. Save results to a csv file.
4. if file not empty, write results to event log.

here is my testing code

```
    $Date=(Get-Date).AddHours(-3)
    $FolderList = "C:\Software\Scripts\FolderList.txt"
    $Folders = get-content $Folderpath
    $Filepath = "C:\Software\Scripts"
    $filename = "$Filepath\" + $timer + "OldFiles.csv"

    foreach ($Folder in $Folders)
  {
    Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -lt $Date -and $_.Attributes -eq "Archive"} | Select Attributes, CreationTime, Fullname | Export-Csv -Path $filename -NoTypeInformation

    }

    if ( (get-childitem $filename).length -eq 0 )

    {

    exit

    }


    else{

    #Write to OpsMgr Log
    $Message = get-content $filename 
    Write-EventLog -LogName "Operations Manager" -Source "Health Service Script" -EventID 402 -EntryType Information -Message "Old files found. $Message"

    }
```

Comment: you have the list of folders saved to `$FolderList` but your `foreach` uses `$Folders`. i presume that is a copy/paste glitch. ///// you use `$timer` to build your output file ... but don't seem to define it. ///// what happens if you write the info for each share to the log independently?

Comment: In addition to that, file Attributes is a Flags value, meaning every bit in the value denotes a different attribute. Files can have many attributes, so to check if the `Archive` bit is set, don't use `$_.Attributes -eq "Archive"`, but do `$_.Attributes -band [System.IO.FileAttributes]::Archive` instead.

Comment: Hi Teo, the $timer was a copy paste error. Its is the first variable defined in the script. I will use $_.Atrtributes indtead.

Comment: @Theo - on my win7ps5.1 setup, i can use `.Attributes -match 'archive'` and get the expected result. you are correct, tho, that there can be more than one attribute ... and `-eq` won't compare as desired. so the OP likely otta use `-match` instead of `-eq`.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Yes, `-match 'archive'` will do because that is the name for the flag attribute. You can even use the attribute's numeric value like `$_.Attributes -band 32`, but that is not very self-descriptive.

Comment: to many typos in a rush to post it. apologies. The $folderlist holds the path list and $folders creates the array when it reads $folderlist (typo here, it shows $folderpath). so it is my understanding that when I do an array show be foreach $folder in $folders. Is that what you are refering to teo?

Comment: @Theo - yep, `32` aint very intuitive ... [*grin*]